# Is it possible to make my PHP website stealth refresh every 1 seconds?

Tags: php

So I have created a really simple website in which I can upload images which are then displayed in the index page, however, if I upload a new image from a different tab, I have to refresh the index in order to have the image appear. Is there a way to make it appear on the index without refreshing as soon as I upload it from the different tab?

Comment: Use, AJAX to load images.

Answer (score 0):

In General for page refresh meta equivalent is used but since you are using PHP achieve can be on following ways

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$seconds = "5";
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $seconds?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo "in 5 seconds ";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can actually achieve this by using auto-refresh the div of where the image is meant to be display

```
$(function() {
startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
$.get('pagelink.php', function(data) {
    $('#content_div_id').html(data);    
});
}
```

or you might be interested in using this advance angular js script https://codepen.io/Mestika/pen/EKWoZz

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JavaScript,

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
location.reload();
},1000);
</script>
```